# Queuing method execution in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, queue

I created messenger which uses **AT commands** and **GSM** modem to communicate but if many users send and receive messages at one time then **AT commands** will overlap and that will cause a lot of problems so I thought that my web app need sort of **FIFO Queue** for storing send/receive method execution.

Let's say I have **HttpPost** method which is executed by pressing **SendMessage**  button on the web page this method saves the message to the database and executes **SendSms** and **ReceiveSms** method which doing stuff with **AT commands** as in the code below.

```
[HttpPost(Name = "add-message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessage([FromBody] MessengerViewModel messengerViewModel)
{  
    AtSmsSender smsSender = new AtSmsSender();
    InnerAtSmsReceiver innerAtSmsReceiver = new InnerAtSmsReceiver(_receivedMessagesService);

    await smsSender.SendSms(messengerViewModel.PhoneNr, messengerViewModel.MessageBody);
    await innerAtSmsReceiver.ReceiveSms();

    //Logic of saving message using service
}
```

I was searching for Queuing examples but mostly what I found was messages queuing which not fits this example as I think. How could I queue this **Http method** or methods inside it that they would be stacked and executed after some delay? 

First time encountered this thing so sorry if I stated question too poorly.

Comment: Message queuing is exactly what you need here. Push the commands onto a queue and let another process deal with them in sequence.

Comment: Message queue would be best. If in memory (and loss of messages) is acceptable then consider using `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @DavidG I see now that message queue is best way,  maybe there is some tips how to push commands into queue?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Comment: As for string messages I understood how it works, but how to pass method into this queue?

Comment: Got an answer for this question in other question that created. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944058/queuing-tasks-in-asp-net-core/50944530?noredirect=1#comment88891503_50944530)